# Transform Tables of Data in Cucumber

Tags: java, spring, testing, cucumber, bdd

I'm working on Cucumber to write BDD tests for a Java program in a spring boot project.

Imagine this table as an example of user given data:

```
Given user wants to buy a T-shirt with the following attributes
  | color | size  |
  | blue  | small |
  | black | large |
```

the problem comes in mapping data, where I'm calling an API which gets data as json and knows `colour` not `color` and gets `S` and `L` as `size` properties not `small` and `large`.

is there any way to auto convert data from tables, including values or headers for tables with more columns and rows?

Comment: Create your own pojo class and then add   @DataTableType to convert the datatable data and when you will try to access the data from the pojo object then  before accessing the data with getter method you can perform some operation that could help you to do the conversion of data as per the requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I will share how I've done that:

first create a POJO for mapping data:

```
@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class TshirtInfo {

    private String colour;

    private String size;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "TshirtInfo [colour: " + colour + ", size: " + size + "]";
    }

}
```

then create a DataTransformer class to map data to POJO:

```
public class DataTransformer implements TypeRegistryConfigurer {

    public DataTransformer () {
        this.map = new HashMap<>();
        this.map.put("small", "S");
        this.map.put("large", "L");
    }

    private Map<String, String> map;

    @Override
    public Locale locale() {
        return Locale.ENGLISH;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureTypeRegistry(TypeRegistry typeRegistry) {
        typeRegistry.defineDataTableType(new DataTableType(TshirtInfo.class,
                        (Map<String, String> row) -> {

                            String colour = row.get("color");
                            String size = this.map.get(row.get("size"));

                        return new LoginInfo(colour, size);
                        }
                )
        );
    }


}
```

finally for using them:

```
public class Stepdefs implements En {

    public Stepdefs () {

        Given("user wants to buy a T-shirt with the following attributes", (DataTable dataTable) -> {

            System.out.println(dataTable);

            List<TshirtInfo> infos = dataTable.asList(TshirtInfo.class);
            System.out.println(infos);

        .
        .
        .
        .
        // other parts of your code

}
```

Output would be like:

```
  | color | size  |
  | blue  | small |
  | black | large |

[TshirtInfo [colour: blue, size: S], TshirtInfo [colour: black, size: L]]
```

That's all.